# Statistics and probability functions

Tags: probability, statistics

So my statistics is a bit rusty, but the following question is given as:

Suppose 14/138 = 0.1 (10%) of patients have been sent to the emergency department in Hospital A.

Suppose that on a random day 10 people are sent to hospital A

a) construct a probability function of the distribution of the patients that might be send to the emergency department in Hospital A

b) What is $\mu$ and $SD$

c) What is the probability that none of the patients will be sent to the emergency department in Hospital A

So for question a) I'm a little bit confused am I supposed to assume that we have a normal distribution, so that will be my probability function of the distribution of the patients?

For question b) Im confused about how to find those value given so little information... I know that 14 out of 138 were sent to the emergency room, but that's it.

c) For c If i am allowed to assume that we have a normal distribution I believe I can use pnorm in rstudio to compute it but I am not sure

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: I think part (a) means you need to construct a reasonable probability mass function (PMF)  $P[X=k]$ for $k \in \{0, 1, 2, ..., 10\}$. Once you have a PMF you can do parts (b) and (c).

Comment: Could you by chance add a reference. Perhaps it could be used to go back and find the distribution in order to find the density function. Could be some background stuff we are missing or maybe a previous question.

Comment: Thank you, then I suppose I have to use binomial distribution? is it correct to say that dbinom(k,n,p) should be dbinom(0,10,0.2) so the answer to c) is 35%?, but I am not sure I can do that becaue then I am not using the answers from a) and b)